# Problemas al ejecutar System.console().readLine(), me sale error

Tags: java

Estoy utilizando System.console().readLine(); y al ejecutalo me sale este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.
..y no me deja ingresar información por pantalla. este es el código que estoy utlizando:
package Uni3_EntradaDeDatos;

public class InputDesdeTeclado {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String nombre;
    System.out.print("Por favor, dime como te llamas: ");
    nombre = System.console().readLine();//metodo para ingresar datos desde
    // el usuario
    System.out.println("Hola " + nombre + " ,Encantado de conocerte!");
    
                 // VERIFICAR, NO ME QUIERE DAR el system.console,readLine
                 //y lo tengo bueno, (en el reply si me da)
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas seguro de que console es una funcion ?

Comment: Por favor, usa un [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) en lugar de System.console().readLine(). Así te evitas estos problemas. Normalmente System.console() devuelve null cuando lo ejecutas en un IDE.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Porque cuando utilizo un System.console().readLine(); en mi programa de netbeans error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/559122/porque-cuando-utilizo-un-system-console-readline-en-mi-programa-de-netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu versión de Java. El código corre bien.
[image: Referencia]

Comment: No es una respuesta. Es un comentario a la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias.