# Porque cuando utilizo un System.console().readLine(); en mi programa de netbeans error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
/**
 * Ejemplo de uso de la clase File
 * Comprobación de existencia y borrado de un fichero
 *
 * @author Luis José Sánchez
 */
class EjemploFichero05 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Introduzca el nombre del archivo que desea borrar: ");
        String nombreFichero = System.console().readLine();
        File fichero = new File(nombreFichero);
        if (fichero.exists()) {
            fichero.delete();
            System.out.println("El fichero se ha borrado correctamente.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El fichero " + nombreFichero + " no existe.");
        }
    }
}
```

Utilizo un codigo simple y puedo colocarlo en terminal y me da el resultado que quiero, pero en netbeans no he podido realizar este programa ya que me da el error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Aunque no puedo reportar tu pregunta como duplicada, alguien ya preguntó [algo similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/550394). Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El formato que habías usado es para Javascript, que no es lo mismo que Java.

Answer (score 3):

`System.console()` devuelve `null`. Entonces te da error porque intentas acceder al método `readLine` de  una referencia `null`.

Normalmente se usa un [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) para la entrada desde la consola en Java. Prueba usando uno. Así:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String entrada = scan.next();

...
```

Comment: Según leí [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4644415), devuelve `null` solo en los IDE. El motivo es lo que no encuentro.

Comment: @padaleiana no sabemos que IDE usa, pero podría ser un [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505044/13419694) si está usando eclipse o que no decidieron implementarlo.

Comment: Según OP menciona en el título, es Netbeans. De todas maneras, también podría ser lo que decís.

Answer (score 0):

Que una máquina virtual tenga una consola depende de la plataforma subyacente y también de la forma en que se invoca la máquina virtual. Si la máquina virtual se inicia desde una línea de comandos interactiva sin redirigir los flujos de entrada y salida estándar, su consola existirá y, por lo general, estará conectada al teclado y la pantalla desde los que se inició la máquina virtual. Si la máquina virtual se inicia automáticamente, por ejemplo, mediante un programador de trabajos en segundo plano, normalmente no tendrá una consola.

Si esta máquina virtual tiene una consola, se representa mediante una instancia única de esta clase que se puede obtener invocando el método System.console(). Si no hay ningún dispositivo de consola disponible, la invocación de ese método devolverá un valor nulo.

una pregunta asociada que te puede ser de [utilidad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078106/system-console-gives-a-nullpointerexception-in-netbeans)

como alternativa podes usar

```
  Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
  String nombreFichero = leer.next();
```

Comment: segui tus pasos y me fue bien, la verdad no entendia ese punto ya que el mismo manual me indicaba realizar esos pasos

Comment: siempre que tengas dudas consulta a la documentación de la clase o el método respectivo :)